# <Grid> and <Row> tags not working in react giving error : bundle.js:9 Error: Minified React error #130

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, jsx

I am developing a sample react-redux application using webpack

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path=require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack'); 
module.exports= {
    entry : './src/app.js',
    output : {
        filename : 'bundle.js',
        path : path.resolve(__dirname,'public')
    },
    watch: true,
    module : {
        rules : [
            {
                test :/\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader : 'babel-loader',
                query : {
                    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**bookList.js**

```
"use strict"
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {getBooks} from '../../actions/booksAction';
import {Grid, Col, Row, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import bookItem from './bookItem';
class BooksList extends React.Component
{
    componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getBooks()
    }

    render()
    {   
        const booksList = this.props.books.map((booksArr)=> {
            return (
                    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={booksArr.id}>
                       testing
                    </Col>
                    )
        })


    return (
            <Grid>
                   {booksList} 
            </Grid>   
            )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    // which data to pass to react component
  return{
    books: state.books.books
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({getBooks:getBooks}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BooksList);
```

**index.html (main page where grid also will load)**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Hello Redux
        </title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>    
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

**error**
bundle.js:9 Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
(bundle.js:9)

I already installed bootstrap, should i need to write anything in webconfig? Can anyone resolve my issue

I have tried to add 'style-loader','css-loader' in presets of webconfig.js but giving error

Comment: Please provie code written for booksList. If there is no bookslist, then it is undefined which may cause this error. Try remove bookslist from render function and check if code works.

Comment: updated the code with bookList

Comment: Well to find which thing is actually causing error, try to remove booksList varable from return block and check if the error is gone.

Comment: I removed {booksList}  and made it as <Grid></Grid> it is showing the error

Comment: If i make <Grid> to <div></div> it is working. Grid, Row, Col tags are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend not using `bindActionCreator`, the [docs](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators/) also recommend not using it with `redux`. It's misleading because the examples in the redux docs are a bit outdated and still use `bindActionCreator`. More on that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754489/when-would-bindactioncreators-be-used-in-react-redux).

In your case, since you're already importing your action, you don't need to use the `bindActionCreator`. You can simply do the below

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    // which data to pass to react component
  return{
    books: state.books.books
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getBooks})(BooksList);
```

As for the error you're getting it's because one of the Components you tried to use is undefined. I noticed you're using `Grid`, try using another component in bootstrap's [library](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/tree/master/src). In the [grid docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/), you can try using a combination of `Container`, `Row`, and `Col` to create a grid system. See below.

```
<Container fluid="md">
  <Row>
    <Col>1 of 1</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

If this is still creating issues try doing it with a `div` and see if it works. The undefined components could be a result of a dependency version mismatch. You could potentially try deleting your `node_modules` and re-installing `react-bootstrap.`

Comment: Yes it worked i changed <Grid> with <Container>, what about <Well>. What is the reason <grid> and <Well> not working

Comment: @sivashanker the issue could be a react-bootstrap version mismatch or maybe you forgot to npm install bootstrap by itself first. It’s also possible that Grid and Well are no longer supported in react-bootstrap v4+ but I can’t confirm.

Comment: ok I have installed bootstrap also. Anyhow its working fine with <Container> thanks